# Using Pandas to read specific data from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .CSV file that has numerous columns. I need to find the three highest values for Pasadena, CA. The relevant columns are 'Provider City', 'Provider State' and 'Average Medicare Payments'. So, I need to find the 3 highest Average Medicare Payments for Pasadena, CA.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
print('The three largest numbers for Pasadena, CA are', nlargest(3, df['Average Medicare Payments']))
```

I can only find the three highest values out of all the values in the Average Medicare Payments column, rather than it being filtered to just Pasadena, CA. Any ideas?

Comment: You might read this first before you post a question :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

fpath = '/path/to/location.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(fpath, sep=',',
                 names=['Provider City',
                        'Provider State',
                        'Average Medicare Payments']
                 ) # you may need to specify 'skiprows' or 'header'

df['Average Medicare Payments'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Average Medicare Payments'])
df_Pasadena = df.loc[(df['Provider City']=='Pasadena') & (df['Provider State']=='CA')]
h3 = df_Pasadena.nlargest(3, 'Average Medicare Payments')
print('The three largest numbers for Pasadena, CA are', h3)
```